# Coordinating Asynchronous Processes: Managing Data Flow from two functions to control another dependent function

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

would just like to ask for what approach I need to use for the completion of my project which is based on python.

DESCRIPTION:
So, I am developing a mobile robot and I am using rplidar and uwb for collision avoidance and positioning, respectively.

Processing Time (if tested separately):

- For rplidar data "get_data_from_LIDAR()" : 2-20ms
- For uwb data     "main_visualizaiton()"  : 1300-2100ms

I want them to run at the same time when the system is activated, however their process completion time for sending/updating the data is different which is asynchronous for me as rplidar is too fast while uwb is slow.

METHODOLOGY/CONCERN:
I already tried to put inside the function of uwb to rplidar and vice versa, but it leads to an error in rplidar which is "Incorrect starting descriptor bytes and wrong body size" and sometimes it gets stuck.
The issue is that the processing of uwb is too slow that's why it is affecting the functioning of rpliar.

PROBLEM:
Both data from the two functions are important to manipulate the function of "controlCenter()".
The data to be sent is under the comment of "#Send Data to Process". I just want them to somehow run separately but still update the variables needed to be use in "controlCenter" but I just cant figure out yet what approach I need to do for this one.

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to address this issue.
Thanks.

By the way, here's the python snippet:

```
#Encapsulation
class robotController:
   def __init__(self):
      #Securing RPLidar Connection
      #Securing UWB Connection

   def get_data_from_LIDAR(self): #Total Process Time: 2ms- 20ms  
      if (self.con_scan):
         try:
            print(self.lidar.info) #Print LIDAR info
            for scan in self.lidar.iter_scans(max_buf_meas=500):
               self.scan_data = [0]*360
               for (_, angle, distance) in scan:
                  intAngle = floor(angle)
                  index = min([359, intAngle])
                  self.scan_data[index] = distance


               # Send Data to Process for ObstacleDetection/Collision Avoidance v Motor Control
               angle340_359 = self.scan_data[340:360] # 340-359 [LEFT FRONT]
               angle0_20 = self.scan_data[0:21]       # 0-20    [RIGHT FRONT]
               angle270_339 = self.scan_data[270:340] # 270-339 [LEFT SIDEMOST]
               angle21_90 = self.scan_data[21:91]     # 21-90   [RIGHT SIDEMOST]
               self.cycle += 1


         except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.con_scan = False
            print("\nLIDAR Stopped!")
            self.lidar.stop()
            self.lidar.disconnect()
            GPIO.cleanup()
            sys.exit()
        
         except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

   def uwb_data_visualization(self): #Total Process Time: 1300ms- 2100ms  
      while True:
         curTime = int(time.time()*1000)

         if (curTime - self.lastExecTime) > self.elapsedTime:
            node_count = 0
            list = self.read_data() # Read UWB data

            for one in list:
               if one["A"] == "1782":
                  self.clean(self.t_a1) # Clear and update anchor A1782's range              
                  self.a1_range = self.uwb_range_offset(float(one["R"]))
                  self.draw_uwb_anchor(-250, 150, "A1782(0,0)", self.a1_range, self.t_a1)
                  node_count += 1

               if one["A"] == "1783":                 
                  self.clean(self.t_a2) # Clear and update anchor A1783's range                             
                  self.a2_range = self.uwb_range_offset(float(one["R"]))
                  self.draw_uwb_anchor(-250 + self.meter2pixel * self.distance_a1_a2, 150, "A1783(" +
                                         str(self.distance_a1_a2)+")", self.a2_range, self.t_a2)
                  node_count += 1
            
            if node_count == 2: # Calculate the tag's position based on the two anchor ranges (CHANGING)              
               
               # Coordinates of Robot Current Position
               x1, y1 = self.tag_pos(self.a2_range, self.a1_range, self.distance_a1_a2)
               print("x1:", x1,"m ","y1:", y1,"m")
               self.clean(self.t_a3)
               self.draw_uwb_tag(x1, y1, "TAGi", self.t_a3)
           
               # Coordinates of Target Position
               x2 = 1.2
               y2 = 1.4
               #print("x2:", x2,"m ","y2:", y2,"m")

               #Euclidean Linear Distance Computation
               distance_between_centers = ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5
               #print("Distance inBetween: ", distance_between_centers)

               distance_threshold = 0.75  # Define a distance threshold (adjust as needed)              
               if distance_between_centers >= distance_threshold:
                  self.draw_line(x1,y1,x2,y2,color="black")
                  self.is_delivery_comple = False
               else:
                  self.draw_line(x1,y1,x2,y2,color="yellow")
                  self.is_delivery_complete = True
    
        
            '''Send Data to Process for Positioning v Motor Control
            x1, y1,
            x2, y2,
            distance_between_centers,
            is_delivery_complete
            '''


            # Pause briefly to allow for updates
            self.lastExecTime = curTime #50ms

      turtle.mainloop()

   def controlCenter(self):
      #Received Data from UWB and RPlidar
      #<No line here for receiving of data>

      #Sample motor contorl logic
      if is_delivery_complete:
         print("stop")
      else:
         print("forward")

        if angle340_359 >= 650 || angle0_20 >= 650:
         print("rotateCW")
      else:
         print("something")


#Initialization
robot = robotController()

#Activating System's Process
while True:
   robot.controlCenter()
```

Comment: If one of the functions is 100-1000 times faster than the other, what benefit do you expect to get from running them separately?  The performance of your program is 99.9% dependent on the slow process.  But I don't understand your question.  When you are ready to use the data from the fast process, why can't you just call the function?  You will have to wait a few milliseconds, but so what?  You just waited 2000 milliseconds on the slow process, an no human user will ever be able to tell the difference.

Comment: It is to address error in rplidar, such as "Incorrect starting bytes or wrong body size". Based from my prev experiments,  I observed that including time.sleep() or multiple print statements in the rplidar function can result in errors. It seems that main_visualization() behaves like that and contributes to this, causing slower processing of rplidar when either of them is executed within the loop.

Comment: Certainly, it heavily relies on the slow process, but it simply doesn't function when I place the lidar function into the uwb function or vice versa. I'm unable to determine the correct approach. Therefore, I believe that if I can execute them separately but concurrently manipulate the data in the controlCenter, it could work.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that doesn't function?  Perhaps there is a better way to write it, rather than abandoning the obvious simple approach in favor of a much more complicated one.  By the way, the purpose of posting code to SO is so that we have something specific to analyze and discuss.  The code you have presented here is not interesting, unfortunately, because it is full of undefined variables - not from your point of view, of course, but from an outsider's point of view.  The SO community can never come close to running or testing the code you're showing us.